# Use of module_exit() in linux kernel platform drivers

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am learning about linux kernel platform drivers referring to the book **LDD for Embedded processors
by Alberto Liberal de los Rios**

It has a *platform_driver_register()* and *platform_driver_unregister()*  that is called from *hello_init()* and *hello_exit()* functions as below.

```
static int hello_init(void) 
{ 
  pr_info("demo_init enter\n"); 
  platform_driver_register(&my_platform_driver); 
  pr_info("hello_init exit\n"); 
  return 0; 
} 
static void hello_exit(void) 
{ 
  pr_info("demo_exit enter\n"); 
  platform_driver_unregister(&my_platform_driver); 
  pr_info("demo_exit exit\n"); 
} 
module_init(hello_init); 
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

My understandings and questions are as follows :

1. The matching of the *compatible* property present in device tree with the *compatible*
   entries in *struct of_device_id* is done during kernel boot time,the driver is loaded and *probe()* called, it means that the platform driver must be built as part of kernel image.So why we need *module_exit()* in platform drivers.
2. If we build platform driver as loadable module(which includes the module_exit() section) then how the *compatible* property matching takes place and how the *probe()* will be called then.

Any inputs on the two queries mentioned and i am new to platform driver understandings.

Comment: Do not conflate (device/platform) drivers with modules; they are distinct (but related) concepts.  E.G. a filesystem handler can be implemented as a loadable module.  So the code you're looking at has references for its driver interface, as well as reference for its module interface.  There's no conflict nor redundancy. "*the driver is loaded ... it means ... driver must be built as part of kernel image.*" -- There's no "*loading*" when the module is already built/linked into the kernel.

Comment: 1. Need to have it to clean up allocated resources at exit stage. 2. It’s done via module aliasing mechanism with a help of user space tools (`udev`).

Comment: Thanks 0andriy. When do we need to build the platform driver as part of kernel image and when do we need to build as kernel module? Any inputs on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. We need `module_exit()` if we are building our module as loadable module only. It is needed for multiple load/unload cycles. Debugging purposes is one example of the case. Another example is hot-pluggable device and optimization of system (unloading corresponding module in order to free resources). `module_exit()` will not be built in kernel image at all when module is built in. If you need to perform some actions on shutdown/reboot you should implement shutdown function in your module.
2. `module_exit()` (as `module_init()`) has nothing to do with `.probe()`. At least for you as for "user" or module developer. In these functions you do some preparations and freeing which are common to all instances of your driver. And finally you register and unregister your driver(s). Module is not driver yet - it's just a piece of code which can be "inserted"/"removed" into/from kernel space. A driver is instantiated by kernel itself before `.probe()` call. `.probe()` called each time when appropriate "compatible" meets in OF/DT. In this function you prepare and allocate all resource for every instantion of your driver, get some data from ypur OF-node (if needed), initialize the hardware (if needed) and finally attach pointers to so called private resources to driver's instance.